# Angular Input Pattern Validation, .Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

Tags: angular

Hi I have a Input field with a pattern, i am writing a if condition to validate the pattern but when i click save it shows .match pattern is undefined how to fix this error i want to validate both when input is empty and when pattern is not matched

```
                      <input
                      #bankName="ngModel"
                      type="text"
                      class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required"
                      [(ngModel)]="item.local_institution_name"
                      name="LocalinstitutionNameChina"
                      [pattern]="chinaValidator"
                      [ngClass]="{
                       invalid:
                       (submitted && (bankName.errors?.pattern || bankName.errors?.required)) ||
                       (bankName.errors?.pattern && item.institution_name == true)
                      }"
                    />
 if (
      payload.item.chinaCase &&
      payload.item.routingLabel == 'CNAPS Code' &&
      payload.item.local_institution_name ==='' || 
      payload.item.local_institution_name === null ||
      payload.item.local_institution_name ===undefined &&
      !payload.item.local_institution_name.match(this.chinaValidator)

    ) {
      this.loader = false;
      this.toaster.pop('error', `Bank Name`, `Invalid:  should be Simplified Chinese characters - 简化字`);
      return;

    }
```

Comment: Post the all related code, like where you declared `selectedCountryValidator` and can you post the exact error with line no etc.

Comment: exact error here when input is empty and i click save it shows error in console (this.payload.item.local_institution_name.match(this.chinaValidator)  cannot read match of undefined

Comment: From where you getting that payload?

Comment: payload is object comes from service

Comment: Then payload.item.localization must be undefined

Comment: Can you console the payload.item?

Comment: how to solve this

Comment: What is the result of `console.log(payload.item)`

Comment: ok will send you result

Comment: Yes, please send it must be minor mistake